# Wordpress: Display various Categories in Dropdown

Tags: wordpress, categories, html-select

i need to display various Categories in Wordpress. The user can choose a class (Pyromancer, Shaman, Warden) of a gametype (Arena, Guides, Montages).
[www.Forge-Movies.com](http://www.Forge-Movies.com) is what i'm talking about. With following code the categories aren't showing. But "Categories" stand in the title of the dropdown (show_option_none=Categories). Apparently what goes wrong when querying.

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" method="get"><div>
<?php  

        if (in_category('montages'))
            {
            $cat_id = get_cat_id('montages');
            $select = wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Categories&echo=0&hierarchical=1&parent='. $cat_id);
            $select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $select); 
            echo $select;
            } 
        elseif (in_category('guides')) 
            {
            $cat_id = get_cat_id('guides');
            $select = wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Categories&echo=0&hierarchical=1&parent='. $cat_id);
            $select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $select);
            echo $select;
            }   
        ?>
<noscript><div><input type="submit" value="View" /></div></noscript></div></form>
```

Funny enough, but the following code is executed.

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" method="get"><div>
<?php 
$cat_id1 = get_cat_id('guides'); 

$select = wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Categories&echo=0&hierarchical=1&parent='. $cat_id1);
$select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $select); 
echo $select; 
?>
<noscript><div><input type="submit" value="View" /></div></noscript></div></form>
```

Sorry for my bad english. I translated some words from german to english.

Comment: Okay, now i have another option, but I don't like this, because the programming is pretty dirty.
I don't like the code. Guides is only one of several categories. Besides guides I've Arena and Montages. Then there are the subcategories for each category. As a result, the code is a mile long.
What do you think? What can I do better or summarize or even completely different?

Comment: Form
<?php 
if (is_category('8') ) {
//Guides
$cat_id1 = get_cat_id('Guides'); 
$select = wp_dropdown_categories('echo=0&hierarchical=1&parent='. $cat_id1);
$select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $select); 
echo $select; 
}elseif (is_category('17') ) {
//Guides-Warden (Warden is one of all subcats)
$cat_id1 = get_cat_id('Guides'); 
$select = wp_dropdown_categories('echo=0&hierarchical=1&parent='. $cat_id1);
$select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $select); 
echo $select; 
} ?>
/Form

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved my problem. This is works for me:

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" method="get" style="display:inline-block;">div>
    <?php
    if (is_category(array('7', '53', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63')) ) 
    {
    //Montages
    $cat_id1 = get_cat_id('montages'); 
    $select = wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Classes&echo=0&hierarchical=1&parent='. $cat_id1);
    $select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $select); 
    echo $select; 
    }
    elseif (is_category(array('6', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70')) ) 
    {
    //Arena
    $cat_id1 = get_cat_id('Arena'); 
    $select = wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Classes&echo=0&hierarchical=1&parent='. $cat_id1);
    $select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $select); 
    echo $select; 
    }
    elseif (is_category(array('8', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77')) ) 
    {
    //Guides
    $cat_id1 = get_cat_id('Guides'); 
    $select = wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Classes&echo=0&hierarchical=1&parent='. $cat_id1);
    $select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $select); 
    echo $select; 
    }
    ?>
    <noscript><div><input type="submit" value="View" /></div></noscript></div></form>``
```